# angular multiple dependency injection

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

This is a general dependency injection question. Obviously I am doing it wrong.

I am trying to get angular-xeditable working in my app.

https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/

I've installed it using bower, and added the appropriate script link to my head.
Now I'm trying to inject it.
The docs say

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["xeditable"]);
```

so, in my app: I do this:

```
portalApp.controller('portalController', 
    ['$scope', '$http','$filter', 'xeditable', 
        function($scope, $http, $filter, xeditable) {
```

but I get the provide error, meaning it can't find xeditable.

```
angular.js:13642Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$injector/unpr?p0=xeditableProvider%20%3C-%20xeditable%20%3C-%20portalController
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you injected `xeditable` into `app`, but refer it in `portalApp`?

Answer (score 0):

OK, duh. It should be

```
var portalApp = angular.module("portalApp", ['xeditable']);

portalApp.controller('portalController', ['$scope', '$http','$filter', function($scope, $http, $filter) {
```

I'm still getting lots of errors, but at least not that one.